# How does one expand the ram Dask has access to?

Tags: dask

Should developers use Dask as a database by publishing large arrays? If so, what is the recommended workflow one should do to increase the ram Dask has access to (besides modifying the machine itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a `dask-worker` process will allocate data until it hits around 60% of the RAM on the machine, at which point it will start spilling least recently used items to disk.

You can limit this behavior with the `--memory-limit` flag.

If you have more machines that you would like to add to the network then you can start dask-workers on those machines as well and point them to the central scheduler

```
host1$ dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
host2$ dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
host3$ dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
```

To your actual question

> Should developers use Dask as a database by publishing large arrays?

This is really a judgment call.  Dask is a tool and can be used in a variety of ways.  Whether or not it should be used depends on the needs of your application.